# How to loop nested Json accessing same th element for all objects?

Tags: javascript, json, nested-loops

I have a Json object that has 4 children: Item, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3.

```
    {
Item: {0: "PD", 1: "1 - Processor Intel Xeon E5-2630", 2: "2 - Additional 
    Processor", 3: "3 - Memory Quantity Increase", 4: "4 - Raid 6 H730/H730p Cabled Chassis", 5: "5 - Hard Drive Quantity Increase", 6: "6 - Perc H730 Raid Controller 1GB", 7: "7 - UEFI BIOS Boot", 8: "8 - Support: ProDeploy", 9: "9 - Hard Drive Support 3 years", 10: "10 - Dell Networking N2024P Switch", 11: "11 - N2024P Switch  - 5 Years Support", 12: "12 - N2024P Switch - Pro Deployment L2 N"},
    Column 1: {0: 0.2, 1: 0.64, 2: 0.67, 3: 0.63, 4: 0.65, 5: 0.74, 6: 0.64, 7: 0.65, 8: 0.63, 9: 0.65, 10: 1.02, 11: 0.71, 12: 0.7},
    Column 2: {0: 0.24, 1: 0.7, 2: 0.69, 3: 0.7, 4: 0.69, 5: 0.79, 6: 0.69, 7: 0.68, 8: 0.67, 9: 0.68, 10: 1.05, 11: 0.74, 12: 0.72},
    Column 3: {0: 0.199, 1: 0.665, 2: 0.652, 3: 0.631, 4: 0.644, 5: 0.698, 6: 0.647, 7: 0.637, 8: 0.622, 9: 0.63, 10: 0.997, 11: 0.698, 12: 0.672}
    }
```

I need to capture the column name (object name) and access the th element for all the objects in orchestrate mode. For example:

Item: PD | Column 1: 0.2 | Column 2: 0.24 | Column 3: 0.199

Item: 1 - Processor Intel Xeon E5-2630 | Column 1: 0.64 | Column 2: 0.7 | Column 3: 0.665

Note: the name of Column 1, Column 2 and Column 3 are dynamic, can be any name when creating this jSon object.

**Additional Info:**

I am using Javascript and I tried doing a loop only in the first object and getting the same position cell for the other objects, but as the other objects' names are dynamic, I don't know how to do it.

```
i = 0
for (column in dfJson){         
    if(i == 0){
        for (item in column){
           console.log(dfJson['Item'][dfJson[obj][item]]); //here I have the value for the first object "Item" in this iteration
            //here I need to collect the value for Column 1 in this same position
            //here I need to collect the value for Column 2 in this same position
            //here I need to collect the value for Column 3 in this same position
}i++;}}
```

Comment: Alan, please add the  language you are trying use and sample code. Things you have tried and didn't work.

Comment: Thank you, added this info in the original topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would access the properties dynamically using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). That way you can iterate over your first property and map the values from the other properties to it. Say, e.G. `PD -> 0.2, 0.24, 0.199`

```js
const dfJson = {
 Item: {0: "PD", 1: "1 - Processor Intel Xeon E5-2630", 2: "2 - Additional Processor", 3: "3 - Memory Quantity Increase", 4: "4 - Raid 6 H730/H730p Cabled Chassis", 5: "5 - Hard Drive Quantity Increase", 6: "6 - Perc H730 Raid Controller 1GB", 7: "7 - UEFI BIOS Boot", 8: "8 - Support: ProDeploy", 9: "9 - Hard Drive Support 3 years", 10: "10 - Dell Networking N2024P Switch", 11: "11 - N2024P Switch  - 5 Years Support", 12: "12 - N2024P Switch - Pro Deployment L2 N"},
    "Column 1": {0: 0.2, 1: 0.64, 2: 0.67, 3: 0.63, 4: 0.65, 5: 0.74, 6: 0.64, 7: 0.65, 8: 0.63, 9: 0.65, 10: 1.02, 11: 0.71, 12: 0.7},
    "Column 2": {0: 0.24, 1: 0.7, 2: 0.69, 3: 0.7, 4: 0.69, 5: 0.79, 6: 0.69, 7: 0.68, 8: 0.67, 9: 0.68, 10: 1.05, 11: 0.74, 12: 0.72},
    "Column 3": {0: 0.199, 1: 0.665, 2: 0.652, 3: 0.631, 4: 0.644, 5: 0.698, 6: 0.647, 7: 0.637, 8: 0.622, 9: 0.63, 10: 0.997, 11: 0.698, 12: 0.672}
};

for (column in dfJson.Item){
    const currentKey = Object.keys(dfJson.Item)[column];
    // dfJson.item[column] -> Value of Item at current column
    console.log(dfJson.Item[column]);
    for (row in dfJson) {
        if (row !== 'Item') {
           // dfJson[row][currentKey] -> Value of dynamic Key that is not Item at current column
           console.log(dfJson[row][currentKey])
        }
    }
}
```